# Selenium just hanging after popup message appears, until popup not closed

Tags: selenium

I got problem with Selenium on my website.

Scenario:
1. Selenium login to site
2. Selenium press on button
3. Window with confirmation appears (example: http://i.piccy.info/i5/17/00/1760017/popup.jpg)
4. But after this, Selenium just hangs. "Selenium Remote Control" also hangs and I can't even activate it. In Selenium RC logs I got: "Command request: click[ChooseClient, on session ...]"
If I manualy select any option in popup, everything continue to work correct.

As I see, problem in click. For some reason click not over after popup appears.

Selenium code:

```
    selenium.click("link=Home");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("btnCReportAdd");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();
    selenium.click("chooseClient");
    assertEquals( selenium.getConfirmation(), "WARNING - any changes made will not be saved." );        

    selenium.isConfirmationPresent());      
    selenium.waitForPopUp("popup", "30000");
```

And this is button code:

GB.common.navigationwarning.init("WARNING - any changes made will not be saved.");

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use a message box (alerts) in a Web Environment. Why don’t you replace it with a modal pop-up (Html Version) ? You can find lots of example if you google it(also Jquery got an Plug-in for that)

Selenium and any web drivers can interact very well with modal pop-up (you can use the CSS or class attribute to understand if a pop up is visible or not)  but they can’t interact with alerts message box

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself using Selenium 2.41, FF 28.

Adding this line before clicking the element to bring up the popup fixed it for me:

```
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.showModalDialog = function( sURL,vArguments, sFeatures) { window.open(sURL, 'modal', sFeatures); }");
```

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/webdriver/window.showModalDialog/webdriver/zp0Kwu6JHCc/fdlUC2xUcugJ)